# How to comment out all script tags in an html document using HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, comments

I would like to comment out all script tags from an HtmlDocument.  This way when I render the document the scripts are not executed however we can still see what was there.  Unfortunately, my current approach is failing:

```
foreach (var scriptTag in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script"))
            {
                var commentedScript = new HtmlNode(HtmlNodeType.Comment, htmlDocument, 0) { InnerHtml = scriptTag.ToString() };
                scriptTag.ParentNode.AppendChild(commentedScript);
                scriptTag.Remove();
            }
```

Note that I can do this using replace functions on the html, but I do not think it would be as robust:

```
domHtml = domHtml.Replace("<script", "<!-- <script");
domHtml = domHtml.Replace("</script>", "</script> -->");
```

Comment: How about changing the language attribute to something the browser can not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var scriptTag in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script"))
        {
            var commentedScript = HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(string.Format("<!--{0}-->", scriptTag.OuterHtml));
            scriptTag.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(commentedScript, scriptTag);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this SO post - very clean solution utilising the Linq query support of the HTML Agility Pack:
[htmlagilitypack - remove script and style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441470/htmlagilitypack-remove-script-and-style)