# htmlagilitypack - remove script and style?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Im using the following method to extract text form html:

```
    public string getAllText(string _html)
    {
        string _allText = "";
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(_html);


            var root = document.DocumentNode;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
            {
                if (!node.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    string text = node.InnerText;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                        sb.AppendLine(text.Trim());
                }
            }

            _allText = sb.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        _allText = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_allText);

        return _allText;
    }
```

Problem is that i also get script and style tags.

How could i exclude them?

Comment: What about an inline style i.e. <p style="bad">? I see it in OuterHtml but would like to strip out all inline styles too.

Comment: `if (childNode.Attributes.Contains("style"))
                    {
                        childNode.Attributes.Remove("style");
                    }
                    if (childNode.Attributes.Contains("class"))
                    {
                        childNode.Attributes.Remove("class");
                    }`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: How do i foreach through that?

Comment: @Jacqueline When you run above code. All `script` and `style` tags will be removed from `doc`

Comment: ahh i see, can it be extenede to support comments such as <!-- comment --> also?

Comment: @Jacqueline `.Where(n => n.Name == "script" || n.Name == "style" || n.Name=="#comment")`

Comment: Does the `Name` property need to be compared case insensitive? I'm thinking the attacker could have used `<SCRIPT>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do so using `HtmlDocument` class:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(input);

doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//style|//script").ToList().ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//style|//script").ToList().ForEach(n => n.Remove());`?

Comment: @Rubanov Yeah it should be, I had an extension method so I didn't require the .ToList in my code. Answer updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some excellent answers, System.Linq is handy!

For a non Linq based approach:

```
private HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument RemoveScripts(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument webDocument)
{

// Get all Nodes: script
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection Nodes = webDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");

// Make sure not Null:
if (Nodes == null)
    return webDocument;

// Remove all Nodes:
foreach (HtmlNode node in Nodes)
    node.Remove();

return webDocument;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string StripStyles(this string html)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();

    document.LoadHtml(html);

    foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        var toRemove = node.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name == "style" || x.Name == "script")
            .ToList();
        foreach (var attribute in toRemove)
        {
            attribute.Remove();
        }
    }

    return document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```