# Regular Expression Remove HTML Tags but NOT HTML comment tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

Below I have the following Regex Expression which I am using to remove the HTML tags from a string object:

```
(?:<style.+?>.+?</style>|<script.+?>.+?</script>|<(?:!|/?[a-zA-Z]+).*?/?>)
```

This expression works well... a little too well. I want to exclude the HTML comment tags like:

- `<!--/ nav -->`
- `<!--end nav-->`
- `<!-- subnavup -->`
- `<!--/ subnavup -->`

Not specifically these examples, but *all* HTML comment tags. What changes to my Regex would I need to do in order to accomplish this?

Comment: 3..2..1 htmlagilitypack.

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Comment: @UweKeim - Does HtmlAgilityPack handle comments usefully?  Or does it ignore them entirely because they're *comments*?

Comment: @Bobson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441470/htmlagilitypack-remove-script-and-style

Comment: Apart from what the other have said... What you're trying to do is explained in detail in this question about [matching pattern x but excluding y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204), have a look.

Comment: To follow up on @L.B's vague comment, the very last comment on the answer to that question shows that HtmlAgilityPack will support comments and assigns them a `.Name` of `"#comment"`.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how in the world is this a duplicate of that other post? This post is asking about general regex use and the other is asking about extracting text using C#?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
(<!--[\S\s]+?-->)
```

I didn't test it, but I'm quite sure it works.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a wrong answer. I'm quite sure.

Comment: Well, your answer misses some argues. I know that Html shouldn't be parsed with regex. Since this case looks for specific start and end of sentences, this ist just here possible... If not, please develop your idea.

Comment: admdrew, Your code finds all of the elements I am trying to exclude. I need this incorporated into my original regex expression to exclude all the comment tags from getting matched.

Comment: Hi,
Actually, I'm not admdrew, but Hermios. Whatever. Then I confirm the other opinion -> Don't parse html with regex!