# Use of " in Regular Expresstion

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

consider this as the input string

```
 <h1 class="h1class"><span style="font-weight: bold;">abc</span></h1>
```

I want a regex to remove `style="font-weight: bold;"` from the above string.

I made a regex for same as style=[\s\w\W]*" , but " at the end of expression is not acceptable.
and also I cannot use \W as the whole line will get selected then `style="font-weight: bold;">abc</span></h1>` but I want `style="font-weight: bold;"`.

can anyone help me out to get the expected result.

Thanx in advance..!

Comment: negative character class -> something like this `[^"]*?"`. Also i would make your quantifier lazy using `?`, so that the first occurence of `"` gets matched.

Comment: For all but the simplest strings a parser like Agility Pack is probably a better approach; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441470/htmlagilitypack-remove-script-and-style

Answer (score 2):

> I want a regex to remove style="font-weight: bold;" from the above string.

Why would you want to use regular expressions for a fixed string replacement? Is `String.Replace` not enough for you?

```
input.Replace(@"style=""font-weight: bold;""", "");
```

That being said, you really should not work on HTML with string methods. Use a parser for any work that is even slightly more complex than the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = @"<h1 class=""h1class""><span style=""font-weight: bold; "">abc</span></h1>";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"style=\"".+?\""", "");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context and explain how it works.  Especially since regexes are not very human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to achieve the desired result using `HtmlAgilityPack`:

```
var html= "<h1 class=\"h1class\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">abc</span></h1>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
hap.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.Descendants("span");
if (nodes != null)
    foreach (var node in nodes)
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((node.GetAttributeValue("style", string.Empty))))
           node.Attributes["style"].Remove();
Console.WriteLine(hap.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="h1class"><span>abc</span></h1>
```

You can further adjust this according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

How about this Regex:

```
<([^>]*)(\sstyle=\".+?\"(\s|))(.*?)>
```

Replace pattern:

```
<$1$3>
```

See this Match.Replace demo on [systemtextregularexpressions.com](http://systemtextregularexpressions.com/r20/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags).

[image]

Result:

[image]