# How to check if an HTML element contains textual content

Tags: c#, winforms, mshtml, innertext

In a C# winform application, I try to check if the `innerText` of an `HtmlElement` is white space or not.

```
 String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(elem.InnerText)
```

The `elem.OuterHtml` is:

```
<div class="ad-container toplb">
 <span class="leader-board">
 <div id="div-gpt-ad-1409955032897-3">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  PbhAdUnit.cmd_push(function() {pbh_ad_units['div-gpt-ad-1409955032897-3'].display(); });
 </script>
 </div>
 </span>
</div
```

The content of `innerText`

```
  PbhAdUnit.cmd_push(function() {pbh_ad_units['div-gpt-ad-1409955032897-3'].display(); });
```

I expect `innerText` to ignore scripts and return empty if there is no readable text (the text which appears on the page) inside the element. Anyway how can I ignore such elements?

Comment: What is  _readable text_?

Comment: @dotctor the text which appears on the page.

Comment: And which element your `elem` is pointing to?

Comment: @dotctor the top div element, the code is its outerhtml

Comment: did you try string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace?

Comment: @Ian yes, but as you see the innerText is not empty

Comment: When I test using `<div id="div1"><script type="text/javascript">alert('');</script><input type="Text"/>Some Text</div>` the inner text for `div1` is `Some Text`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yeah and I want to detect and ignore such elements, which contain no content

Comment: I see, so the scripts makes your work harder... Not sure if regular expression with detection on `;$</script>`at the end-of-line could help. But it may be worth trying. And Merry Christmas btw!

Comment: In my sample, it returns `Some Text` as inner text  and it seems it ignores them. How do you get the inner text?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Really! you could test the given html in the question, what returns for it

Comment: The content of `<div class="ad-container toplb">` is empty string.

Comment: how do you check for inner text?

Comment: @RezaAghaei using `elem.InnerText`, its strange, in my case it wasn't empty as the Watch window in debug shows, I copied both of them from the Watch window

Answer (score 2):

You can find the inner text of an element using [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) property. It returns all inner text removing markup.

**Sample Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(@"d:\sample.html");
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var div = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div1");
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}'", div.InnerText), "InnerText");
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("'{0}'", div.InnerHtml), "InnerHtml");
}
```

**Sample Content:**

Create a `sample.html` file using below content.

```
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"><script type="text/javascript">alert('Hi');</script><input type="text"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

I put `''` around inner text and inner html:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, anyway I don't have this problem now as I remove scrip tags using the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441470/htmlagilitypack-remove-script-and-style, but I expected you try my original html.

Comment: I also tried using your original html and the result is the same. But to keep the answer more general and more useful for future readers, I used above values for answer.  You can simply put your desired content in this sample and see the result :)

Comment: Thank you, I must debug it again. Actually, my problem has been with the `InnerText` itself. I will notify you.