# Remove all Inline Javascript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, string

I have a string:
`` `<p onclick="alert('abc')" style="color: black">text</p>` ``

I want to remove all Javascript like `onclick, onchange, ...` leaving only HTML and CSS. is there any way to do this in C#? the only way I can think of is to remove each javascript tag from the string.

Input: `<p onclick="alert('abc')" style="color: black">text</p>`

Output: `<p style="color: black ">text</p>`

Comment: 1. Parse the HTML using a library like HtmlAgilityPack. 2. Loop through all the elements checking their attributes for inline js. 3. Remove said attributes. 4. Write new HTML to file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65947149/3181933 - this pretty much does what you want except for the names of the attributes being different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) to remove the inline java script for provided HTML fragment.

For ex - the following code

```
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
var html = @"<script>alert('xss')</script><div onload=""alert('xss')"""
    + @"style=""background-color: test"">Test<img src=""test.gif"""
    + @"style=""background-image: url(javascript:alert('xss')); margin: 10px""><p onclick =""alert('abc')"" style =""color: black"">text</p></div>";
var sanitized = sanitizer.Sanitize(html);
```

returns the output as

```
<div>Test<img src="test.gif" style="margin: 10px"><p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)">text</p></div>
```

You can check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/892nOk) fiddle for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/remove-attribute). I have linked tha page you need in its documentations.

Use it like this:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var pNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p");   
pNode.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oKIrac) is the fiddle.